# Table created with sqlContext.createExternalTable is not visible after restart of spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am creating hive external table using the following statement 
          `sqlContext.createExternalTable(tableName, "parquet", someDF.schema, Map("path" -> path))` 
After restart of spark, the table created is not visible. 
Is it possible somehow to create a hive table persisted in tachyon using spark with existing schema from some data frame ? 
I would like the table schema to be preserved in hive metastore. Is it possible ?

With best regards,
Michael

Comment: Are you using Spark 1.x or 2.x?   2.x has SparkSessions, which would be useful to solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Work with HiveContext instead of SQLContext. From the SparkSQL and DataFrame guide:

> When working with a HiveContext, DataFrames can also be saved as persistent tables using the `saveAsTable` command. Unlike the registerTempTable command, `saveAsTable` will materialize the contents of the dataframe and create a pointer to the data in the HiveMetastore. Persistent tables will still exist even after your Spark program has restarted, as long as you maintain your connection to the same metastore. A DataFrame for a persistent table can be created by calling the table method on a SQLContext with the name of the table.
>
> By default `saveAsTable` will create a “managed table”, meaning that the location of the data will be controlled by the metastore. Managed tables will also have their data deleted automatically when a table is dropped.

Because HiveContext inherits from SQLContext, you lose no functionality from that aspect and you gain the ability to find tables in the Hive metastore as well as write queries in HiveQL. You can find more information about using HiveContext [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#starting-point-sqlcontext) and find an example of its use [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/hive/HiveFromSpark.scala).

Comment: Is it possible to create parquet table saved in tachyon using saveAsTable call? I am not sure, that it is possible